# PHP PDO data into Json_Encode + but only first line appears

Tags: php, json, select, pdo, encode

```
                       $sql='SELECT word,language,acceptable FROM profanity;';
                       $pds=$database_miscellaneous->pdo->prepare($sql); 
                       $pds->execute(); 
                       //$row=$pds->fetch();
        foreach($pds as $row) {
            $profanityText = json_encode(array('word' => $row['word'],
                                       'language' => $row['language'],
                                       'acceptable' => $row['acceptable']));
        }
```

I have the above code. The catch is it works but only the first line from the database goes into the json array. I've run the query directly against the DB and it pulls all the data.

I'm guessing my foreach loop has an issue or many the way I'm doing the PDO call.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's the _first_ row, not the _last_? You overwrite the content of $profanityText in each iteration...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the variable holding the json encoded values `$profanityText` gets overidden every time in the loop.

Use this

```
    $rows = array()
    foreach($pds as $row) {

        $rows[] = array('word' => $row['word'],
            'language' => $row['language'],
            'acceptable' => $row['acceptable']);
    }
    $profanityText = json_encode($rows);
```

Or, if you are not manipulating your data in anyway, you can just directly call (as mentioned by deceze)

```
$profanityTest = json_encode($pds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: Or just `json_encode($pds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`.

Comment: @deceze, may be OP is trying to manipulate the content is some way, at the loop. I presumed that.

Answer (score 2):

You are just assigning each new value to `$profanityText` but it should be appended like this edit.

```
$profanityText = array();
foreach($pds as $row) {
    $profanityText[] = array('word' => $row['word'],
                                   'language' => $row['language'],
                                   'acceptable' => $row['acceptable']);
}

echo json_decode($profanityText);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's PDO, dude!
Do not Repeat Yourself when you can:

```
$sql='SELECT word,language,acceptable FROM profanity;';
$pds=$database_miscellaneous->pdo->prepare($sql); 
$pds->execute(); 
$profanityText = json_encode($pds->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```